# Confused about hoisting

Tags: javascript, hoisting

consider these slightly two different versions of hoisting...

```
mylocation = "dublin" 
function outputPosition() {
    alert(mylocation);
    mylocation = "fingal" ;
    alert(mylocation);
}
outputPosition();
```

This will output "fingal" and then "fingal"

```
mylocation = "dublin" 
function outputPosition() {
    alert(mylocation);
    var mylocation = "fingal" ;
    alert(mylocation);
}
outputPosition();
```

This will output "undefined" and "fingal"

Why?

Comment: The first one should throw a ReferenceError unless `mylocation` was already defined somewhere else.

Comment: @GGG. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcrVH/)

Comment: @gdoron nice work, psychic detective :D

Comment: You ruined the question with last your edit, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8kMP/). It doesn't alert what you wrote... by the way, only the second one is about `hoisting`, the first is about `scope`

Comment: The output of first one must be "dublin" and "fingal" provided that mylocation is defined,otherwise its a reference error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you declare variable using `var` keyword within a javascript function and no matter where you put this declaration - at the top of the function or at the buttom, it will be considered as local variable. So that is why you get `undefined` when you try to get value of such variable before `var` declaration.

Answer (score 5):

In the second option, you hide `mylocation` (which I hope was declared in outer scope.) with a new variable via the `var` declaration.

*"In JavaScript, variable can be declared after being used."* meaning: JavaScript pulls up `var` declarations to the top of the scope(**No matter where it was declared!**), so in your second function `var mylocation` is implicitly defined but not assigned before the first alert, hence it output `undefined` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The output of first snippet must be "dublin" and "fingal" provided that mylocation is defined,otherwise its a reference error.

For more details :

http://bustingseams.blogspot.in/2009/08/another-javascript-pitfall-hoisting.html

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript - variable declarations are *hoisted* but initialization is *not*.
That means that when you write `var` anywhere inside a function it will be treated as declared in top. So it will not take the same name variable from global space.

@Ashish is right, the first snippet should output "dublin" and "fingal".

Answer (score 0):

Take for example :

```
x = 5;
var x;

console.log( x );
```

Technically you might want to look at `x = 5;` as a wrong statement in this context considering the fact that it comes before the declaration, but the JS Engine doesn't work that way. It sees `x = 5` and `var x` as two separate statements, the first one a compiler-related task, and the second one an execution-related task.

what this means in simple terms is that all declarations in a scope, regardless of where they appear, are processed first before the code itself is executed. i.e you can execute a variable before declaring it.